# geting json from a api using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, api

I'm Trying to get the json from http://api.arbetsformedlingen.se/ with jquery, but I can't get it to work!
I tried for 4 hours and now i give up...

I thought maybe it's a cross domain issue so I tried
http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/

And allso tried to get the xml and the using this
http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/xml-to-json/

But it did't worked..
I don't want to use php-proxy method to get the xml file.

Why can't I just get the json files from the api?
everytime i tried to get the xml or json file it returns a empty page.

here is one of the exemples

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// Checking if jQuery is working
console.log("jQuery running");
var myurl="http://api.arbetsformedlingen.se/platsannons/soklista/kommuner?lanid=10";
console.log(" call back url :"+ myurl);
$.ajax({
    url: myurl,
    type: 'Get',
    cache: false,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(json) {
     console.log(" reponse :"+ json);
                }  
            });         
});
```

Comment: If the api does not support jsonp, you can't get the data through javascript.

Comment: it says that it supports application/json & application/xml...

Comment: so how can i use the json output? how can i access it? i can't get the xml due to the cross domain... is the php-proxy my last chans?